# Find a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f'(x)| < 1$ and $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**Exercise**: Find a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f'(x)| < 1$ and $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

I got this exercise from the book "Curso de Análise: volume 1", by Elon Lages Lima. (In Portuguese).

My attempts include

$1$) integrate $\frac{2\text{arctan}(x)}{\pi}$, but I get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%282+x+tan%5E%28-1%29%28x%29-log%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29%2Fpi%2B2%2C+plot+x). (Adding larger constants doesn't seem to help.)

$2$) $f(x) = \text{sin}(x/2) + x + 2$ but its derivative gets too large.

Any ideas?

Comment: Notice that by Banach's fixed point theorem, $|f'(x)|$ must go to $1$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$ or $x\rightarrow-\infty$.

I know it's not really of any help towards a solution, but it is a nice fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any [branch of the hyperbola](http://wolfr.am/jYFNct) $y^2-x^2=1$. It doesn't cross the line $y=x$ and satisfies the required condition.

Comment: Thanks! [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2*arctan%28x%29%2Fpi%2C+plot+x%5E2%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+1%29%2C+plot+x%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29)'s a comparison between the derivatives in: my first attempt, N.S.'s answer and your answer. As you can see, mine takes too long to get close to 1 (as x goes to infinity), which kind of explains why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=x-\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks, N.S.! May I ask you how you got this function? Did you integrate the function $\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$? I'm asking this because a friend of mine was trying to use "rotation" (I'm not sure what he means about that) and he mentioned the function arctan$(x)$, so I'm just wondering if you used this alternative method.

Comment: @TuringMachine If you are familiar with Banach Fixed point theorem, it implies that for any such example, $f(x)$ needs to get arbitrarily close to $1$. So I looked a function of the type $1-g(x)$, where $0 \leq g(x) \leq 1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=0$ and which is easy to integrate...Note that to get no fixed point, all you need is that the antiderivative of $g(x)$ has no root.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a function that tends to 0 at $-\infty$, and tends to $x$ at $+\infty$. For instance, a hyperbola with asymptotes y=0 and y=x.

Do you know how to construct such a hyperbola?